# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable using Python Click library

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, python-click

I'm trying to execute a Python 3 script via the command line with the Click library but it seems that it isn't working as it should.

`@click.option('--criteria', default='', type=click.STRING, envvar="CRITERIA")`

That is the given line which throws the `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`. Should I be doing something else or is it a matter of syntax?

**UPDATE**

Having changed the placement of the `criteria` option few places above, now I see that the error mentioned before is given in the last placed option, no matter the type. This is my method signature and the places where the parameters are used.

```
@click.command('my_command', 'Initialize my_command')
@click.option('--s1', type=click.STRING, envvar='S_1',
              help='s1')
@click.option('--s2', type=click.STRING, envvar='S_2',
              help='s2')
@click.option('--i', type=click.STRING, envvar="I")
@click.option('--c', type=click.STRING, envvar="C")
@click.option('--l', default='[]', type=click.STRING, envvar="L")
@click.option('--st', default='[]', type=click.STRING, envvar="ST")
@click.option('--s', default='[]', type=click.STRING, envvar="S")
def my_command(s1, s2, i, c, l, st, s):
    ...
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/project_root/__main__.py", line 27, in <module>
    @click.command('my_command', 'Initialize my_command')
  File "/project_root/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 115, in decorator
    cmd = _make_command(f, name, attrs, cls)
  File "/project_root/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 89, in _make_command
    callback=f, params=params, **attrs)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Show the full code and the full traceback.

Comment: Could you please provide some more of the surrounding code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman sorry for the delay. Check the update as I've been checking and the error repeats for the last option in the stack of 'option', even if I just leave the click.command anotation.

Comment: When do you get this error? How did you try to run the script and with what command line options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
@click.command('my_command', 'Initialize my_command')
```

This is the signature of `click.command`:

```
click.command(name=None, cls=None, **attrs)
```

The `name` defaults to the function name. So no need to use it because you just use the function name anyway.
You use a string as `cls`, which defaults to `click.Command`.

So just use it like this:

```
@click.command(help='Initialize my_command')
```